# How to extend a command in bash so that it expands based on options?

Tags: bash, shell-script, git

I've started working with a git repository that includes a large amount of content that should be assumed readonly.  So, every time I throw a new branch:

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

it should be followed by the command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged LARGE_READONLY_DIRECTORY
```

I figured this would be a perfect opportunity to try my fledgling bash skills, so that all I need to do at the shell is the first line, and it would execute that, then the second, without me remembering to do it (which I won't).

I figured what I want to do is have a function in my .bashrc that checks whether the first argument is 'checkout', and the second it '-b'.  That first check is easy, but I can't figure out how to note the presence of -b.

```
git() {
    if [[ $1 == 'checkout' ]] && [[$2 == '-b']]; 
            then echo 'yep!';
    fi;

    command git "$@";
}
```

When I execute this, it complains that `[[-b: command not found`.  Presumably the fact that it's an option, rather than an argument, is important here.  Can anyone tell me how to check for the presence of that argument, so I know to execute the follow-up command?

Comment: It's generally recommended that you do not name your aliases, functions and scripts the same as a command you are using, as that could lead you to make mistakes when you're working on a system that *doesn't* have those aliases, functions, etc. set up.

Comment: While you've had your answer, this is a risky approach. Parsing git's command line is going to get complicated very quickly, you won't get it right every time. Git provides a lot of hooks, hopefully one of them will apply to your situation.

Comment: @Gilles Point taken.  You inspired me to lookup such hooks, and indeed the post-checkout hook does EXACTLY what I want.  So I'll be taking that approach instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between `[[` and `$2`.

For bash `[[` is not syntax, it is a builtin command (or keyword to be precise). Bash will execute `[[` with all its parameters, including the closing `]]`. When you have no space between `[[` and `$2` bash will not see the keyword `[[`, instead it will see this thing: `[[-b` (after expanding `$2` to `-b`). Bash will then try to execute the string `[[-b` as a command and fail. See `help [[` for more information.

For the same reason you also need a space before the closing `]]`.

Here is your code fixed:

```
git() {
    if [[ $1 == 'checkout' ]] && [[ $2 == '-b' ]]; 
            then echo 'yep!';
    fi;

    command git "$@";
}
```

See also the [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and the [bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ). IMO the best way to learn bash scripting... or the best way to learn not to do too much bash scripting.

Answer (score 1):

As you have no space between `[[` and `$2`, it is parsed incorrectly (as `[[` directly followed by the expansion of `$2`). You need whitespace between the arguments to `[[`:

```
[[ $2 == -b ]]
```